# PHP 7 - Expected an object instance when accessing an instance property

Tags: php

I am using PHP Phan to scan through some code and ensure PHP 7 compatibility before upgrade. It is reporting an issue with the following...

```
if(!empty($values->custom_field['section'][0]['value'])):

Expected an object instance when accessing an instance property, but saw an expression $values with type null
```

I am not sure what is causing the error. How can I resolve it?

Comment: How have you initialised $values? Where have you done it?

Answer (score 2):

`$values` is an object, since it needs to have a `custom_field` property. For some reason your tool believes `$values` to be `null` in that instance.

Why that should be the case, I do not know. I have seen this happen with code such as,

```
$values = null;
if (SOMETHING THAT SHOULD ALWAYS HAPPEN) {
    $values = functionReturningObject();
}
/*
if (null === $values) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Impossible error!');
}
*/
if (empty($values->property)) {
    ...
}
```

In the above case, *sometimes* explicitly testing the object for nullity or objectness is enough to remove the warning.

In some cases, the warning is actually correct:

```
$values = null;
switch ($flag) {
    case 0:
        $values = ...;
        break;
    case 1:
        $values = ...;
        break;
    case 2:
        $values = ...;
        break;
}
```

In the above case, the tool is warning you that in the unforeseen *default* case, however unlikely that might be, `$values` will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The function `empty()` doesn't care whether or not its parameter is defined or makes sense. `empty` returns false if `$values` is not defined or null, but also when it's not an object or when it is an object without the `custom_field` property. And if that property exists but it's not an array it also returns false. If it is an array but doesn't have the key `section` it again returns false.

PhpStan shows this message because it thinks that `$values` is null. It's possible that this is correct, you would have to check the code to find where $value is defined/assigned. But since it is used in `empty` it will not cause runtime problems. If $values is always null then the check just makes your code more complex.